# Run/Debug it:test from intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

Does anybody know if it is possible to run and debug activator it:test from intellij? Especially the debugging of the tests would save me a lost of time developing them.

it:test can AFAIK only be run with the activator command, which I cannot call using intellij run configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an "SBT Task" run configuration from IntelliJ that calls the it:test task. You can run and debug this normally.

[image: Screenshot: Debug/Run Configurations]

If you have the setting `fork in IntegrationTest := true` it is a little more complicated. You will also need to add debug settings to the `javaOptions` in sbt; for example:

```
javaOptions += "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

and in IntelliJ create a Remote run configuration that attaches to the port you configured in sbt:

[image]

You can now run the sbt task and then run the remote config for debugging.